# Condition import of dart:io or dart:html

Tags: flutter, file, flutter-web

I need to use the File class which is different (as for what I understand) in web and html

I would like to be able to do

```
import if (dart.library.io) 'dart:io' if (dart.library.io) 'dart:html';
```

but this doesn't work.

What is the solution to reading File from dart:io on mobile apps and from dart:html in web?

Thank you

Comment: You can import both packages with 'as' keyword, like dart:io as dart_io and dart_html as dart_html and then call function with these alias  according to your requirements on different platform

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [cross_file](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_file) package can help you. Or you can use conditional imports like :

```
import 'dart:io' if (dart.library.html) 'dart:html';
```